# How to use an ObjectDataSource in another ContentPlaceHolder?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to use an ObjectDataSource for multiple DropDownList, but all of them are not in one ContentPlaceHolder. So the code is compiling correctly but I get this exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The DataSourceID of 'DROPDOWNLIST_NAME' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID 'OBJECTDATASOURCE_NAME' could not be found.
```

Obviously I couldn't move all of them to one place and I'm not going to duplicate ObjectDataSource neither!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use special format for DataSourceID of your control in another ContentPlaceHolder (in my case the DropDownList which is not at the same ContentPlaceHolder of ObjectDataSource).

Suppose that ContentPlaceHolder which has ObjectDataSource is **CPH** and ObjectDataSource Id is **OBJDS**, then DataSourceId of your bind control should be like this:

**DataSourceId="CPH$OBJDS"**

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to not use ObjectDataSource and populate dropdownlist controls manually. So you can divide Business Logic and UI.
Eg:

```
public void GetItems(ListControl list, bool emptyElement)
{
     if (list == null)
        return;

     list.Items.Clear();

     if (emptyElement)
        list.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", ""));

     IList<MyClass> foos = Controller.LoadRecords();
     foreach (MyClass foo in foos)
     {
         ListItem item = new ListItem(foo.Description, foo.Id.ToString());
         list.Items.Add(item);
     }
}
```

Called using

```
Manager.GetItems(myDropDownList, true);
```